# TABLEAU Using parameters with comma delimited values

Tags: tableau-api

In Tableau I have a parameter "Salesperson" that has one sales person matched to multiple clients.

```
Client1,Client2,Client3,Client4                | Evan W.
Client5,Client6,Client7                        | Jake R.
Client8,Client9,Client10,Client11,Client12     | Evie A.
Client13                                       | Douglas M.
```

and so on. There are dozens of salespeople, with up to 20-30 clients per salesperson.

Now on to my question. I want to filter based on these sales people but Tableau won't read the values unless it is a single client name. Of the examples above only Douglas M. will return data, Tableau can't read the rest because they are comma delimited.

*How can I configure this parameter in such a way that will allow me to filter for sales people with multiple clients that are comma delimited?*

Comment with follow up questions, I'll be at work for the next 6 hours.

Comment: I think this would also involve using string calculations, aka extracting the Client name from the string of client names.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tableau: How to filter with parameters from comma delimited lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31840309/tableau-how-to-filter-with-parameters-from-comma-delimited-lists)

Comment: Isn't this the same question you asked yesterday? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31840309/tableau-how-to-filter-with-parameters-from-comma-delimited-lists

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to pass multiple values into a parameter (not a dimension) then it is not possible. A parameter is a single-value, and cannot be multiple select.

If you are trying to pass data to filter a dimension, make sure you have this filter on the dashboard set as 'multi-select'. Next you can encode your comma values by **%2C**, so you're URL would look like: `www.yoururl.com/...&ClientList=Firstclient%2CClient2%2CClient3`